# howto convert roman into arabic numeral

Tags: macros, roman-numerals

I know that there is a command \romannumeral that converts numbers in roman numeral

```
\romannumeral3
```

gives iii

Is there a converse like

```
\arabicnumeral{x}
```

that should produce 10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `etoolbox` package has a `\rmntonum` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\rmntonum{MMXV}

\rmntonum{mmxvi}

\rmntonum{mMxViI}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There should be a “classical” package, but `expl3` includes it out of the box; it's just a matter of defining an interface to it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\arabicnumeral}{m}
 {
  \int_from_roman:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\arabicnumeral{x}

\arabicnumeral{MMXV}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to do this at TeX primitive level. The `\romantonum` macro is defined here with usage `\romantonum{mmcdvii}`. This prints 2407.

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\romantonum#1{\tmpnum=0
   \lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\romantonumA#1\end{}}\the\tmpnum}
\def\romantonumA#1{\ifx#1\end\else
   \ifx#1m\advance\tmpnum by1000 \let\next=\romantonumA
   \else \def\next{\romantonumB#1}%
   \fi \expandafter\next \fi
}
\def\romandef#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
   \def#1##1##2{\ifx##1\end\else
      \ifx##1#6\ifx##2#4\advance\tmpnum by9#3 \let\next=#1%
               \else \ifx##2#5\advance\tmpnum by4#3 \let\next=#1%
                     \else \advance\tmpnum by1#3 \def\next{#1##2}%
               \fi   \fi
      \else    \ifx##1#5\advance\tmpnum by5#3 \def\next{#1##2}%
               \else \def\next{#2##1##2}%
      \fi      \fi
      \expandafter\next \fi
}}
\romandef\romantonumB\romantonumC{00}mdc
\romandef\romantonumC\romantonumD{0}clx 
\romandef\romantonumD\romantonumE{}xvi 
\def\romantonumE#1\end{\errmessage{romantonum: something wrong}}

\romantonum{mmcmlvii}
\romantonum{MMXV}

\end
```

Comment: Does this also work under `\def\rnum{MMXV}\romantonum{\rnum}` (not tested)?

Comment: Note that both `\rmntonum` of `etoolbox` and `\int_from_roman:n` of `expl3` are fully expandable. But they use `\numexpr`

Comment: @Werner OK, I've added two `\expandafters` in order to work your example :).

Comment: @egreg I am not able to imagine why somebody explicitly needs this feature fully expanable. Anytime, when user needs to use this in `\edef` or `\write` then he/she can do something like `\prepareout` before `\edef` or `\write` and then use `\the\tmpnum`. With a small knowleges about `\csname` and `\endcsname` it is possible to do this in asynchronous write too. I spent 10 minutes of my time with programming this because the programming at TeX primitive level is entertaining. The similar thinks used in the code cannot be used in any other programming language.