# How to convert Roman into Arabic numeral

Tags: macros, etoolbox, roman-numerals

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227862/6865 explains how to convert Roman into Arabic numerals, but when compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\xdef\test{VII}
\begin{document}
\rmntonum{VII} corresponds to \test\par
\rmntonum{\test} should not be -1!
\end{document}
```

it results in:

`7 corresponds to VII
-1 should not be -1!`

Probably `\rmntonum` sees `\test` instead of `VII`, but even `\expandafter\rmntonum{\test}` did not work. How can I "feed" some variable to `\rmntonum` (or how can I convert it otherwise)?

Comment: You've got your `\expandafter` in the wrong place: you are trying to expand `{`! `\expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\test}`

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes: `\expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\test}` works fine. Please turn your comment into an answer (and please add a line to the etoolbox manual for people as stupid as me...). And thanks and +1!

Comment: I didn't post as an answer as really this is nothing to do with the specific case here: it's the general issue of misunderstanding how `\expandafter` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\expandafter\rmntonum{\test}` expands to `\rmntonum{\test}` since `\expandafter` applies to `{` (skipping over `\rmntonum`, as the name implies). What you're after is `\expandafter\rmntonum\expandafter{\test}` in order to expand `\test`. You can update `\rmntonum` to do this by default:

> 7 corresponds to VII
>   7 should not be -1!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\test{VII}
\let\oldrmntonum\rmntonum
\renewcommand{\rmntonum}[1]{\expandafter\oldrmntonum\expandafter{#1}}

\begin{document}

\rmntonum{VII} corresponds to \test

\rmntonum{\test} should not be -1!

\end{document}
```

You could save some keystrokes

```
\let\oldrmntonum\rmntonum
\renewcommand{\rmntonum}{\expandafter\oldrmntonum\expandafter}
```

but it requires you to explicitly brace the argument to `\rmntonum` (rather than, say, `\rmntonum\test`). Of course, this is not a bad idea in general.

Comment: You can allow `\rmntonum\test` by using an intermediate macro: `\def\rmntonum#1{\rmntonumaux{#1}}` and `\def\rmntonumaux#1{\expandafter\oldrmntonum\expandafter{#1}}`

Answer (score 7):

It's a matter of turning a kernel function into a user level command, with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\romantoarabic}{m}
 {
  \int_from_roman:f { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_roman:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\romantoarabic{VII}

\newcommand{\seven}{VII}

\romantoarabic{\seven}

\end{document}
```

This prints two 7’s.

You can even do

```
\romantoarabic\seven
```

(but I wouldn't recommend it).

If you are using LuaLaTeX, there's a slicker definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\etoolboxrmntonum\rmntonum
\renewcommand{\rmntonum}[1]{%
  \expanded{\noexpand\etoolboxrmntonum{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\test{VII}
\newcommand\another{X\test}

\begin{document}

\rmntonum{VII} corresponds to \test

\rmntonum{\test} should not be -1!

\rmntonum\test{} should not be -1!

\rmntonum{C\another} should not be -1!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and +1, although I accepted Werner's answer (because it is not possible to accept more than one answer).